# KeDei 3.5" v6.3 TFT Display with Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspbian, display, pixel

So I just purchased a KeDei 3.5" TFT Display (v6.3) for my Raspberry Pi 3, and I have found out that the display only works with premade Raspbian / Ubuntu / Kali images. This wouldn't be a problem, but those modified images don't seem to work with HDMI. What I want is to be able to use HDMI with my TV/Monitor, and when I take my Pi to go, I'd like to just be able to plug the display into the Pi. I installed the [drivers](http://en.kedei.net/raspberry/v6_1/LCD_show_v6_1_3.tar.gz) on Raspbian Pixel, when booting up the Pi with the KeDei display after installing the drivers, it just froze on the console. I plugged in an HDMI monitor (while the display was still plugged in) and rebooted my Pi, and it went past the console and booted to the Desktop on the HDMI monitor, but not on the LCD Display.

How can I get the KeDei LCD Display, as well as HDMI to work, on, preferably, the latest Raspbian PIXEL?

**I should also mention that this is a touch display, so I'd like to keep the touch working.**

**EDIT: I installed the drivers on Raspbian Jessie Lite (no gui Raspbian) and it worked, but it broke HDMI :(**

Thanks in advance!

Drivers / IMG Link: http://en.kedei.net/raspberry/raspberry.html

Comment: Hi @Leo, instead of adding 'solved' to your title or adding the solution in your question, you can post an answer below if you have enough detail to answer your own question. Once you click the green checkmark, your question will be marked solved by the system automatically; you don't need to do this yourself. Good to hear you found a solution to your problem though.

Comment: How did you actually solved your issue? Please specify what did you download, how did you install the driver?

Comment: Follow this guide: http://www.epyon.be/2019/01/12/raspberry-pi-3-b-with-kedei-3-5-inch-480x320-tf-lcd-display/#comment-161327 Make sure you only have one 'dtoverlay' setting in your '/boot/config.txt' file and don't forget to repeat this process every time you perform a kernel package upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same hardware and screen. If you still have the instruction manual, it answers your question in the FAQs section. I can't upload the picture from the manual for some reason, but the answer given for "How can I change from LCD to HDMI output? Will I need (a) driver?" is:

"Yes, you have to format the SD card, then download the driver for HDMI. If you need to change output frequently, we suggest you prepare two SD cards with different drivers, one for LCD and another for HDMI."

Hope it helps. Online user manual available at http://www.osoyoo.com/?p=968

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the drivers on the LATEST build (January 2017) of Raspbian PIXEL and it worked! Conveniently enough, the drivers came with scripts to switch between HDMI and LCD! So I put those scripts on my Desktop and now I'm able to switch between HDMI and LCD easily!

Answer (score 2):

There is an open source driver now for SPI bus to this device.  Also supports touch.

https://github.com/kpishere/fbcp-ili9341.git